# RIP Bernard Cribbins

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Bernard Cribbins has died aged 93, according to [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-62330478) and [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2022/jul/28/bernard-cribbins-star-of-doctor-who-and-jackanory-dies-aged-93). Probably best remembered for his role in The Railway Children, Cribbins also appeared in two formats of Dr Who: alongside Peter Cushing in Daleks – Invasion Earth: 2150 A.D. and alongside David Tenant in the relaunched series as Wilfred Mott. Here he is, in character, stargazing with Donna Noble in Partners in Crime.

[image: Still from Doctor Who, as described above]

Also memorable (though not SFF) was his role as Mr Hutchinson in Fawlty Towers. Here he is, about to receive a parting gift from Mr Fawlty himself.

[image: Still from Fawlty Towers, showing Bernard Cribbins acting alongside John Cleese and Andrew Sachs]

Comment: I sadly missed out on most of Cribbins' work.  The one thing I really remember him from is an episode of _Space 1999_ called "Brian the Brain."  I think I need to rectify this oversight and check out some of his other work.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one possible reaction to this news:

[image]

Here's a lesser known, non SFF, appearance of Bernard Cribbins. It's much older than the others, from 1962, before Doctor Who was created and before John Cleese had made his name in comedy.

Comment: Right Said Fred is probably the first thing I think of when thinking of Bernard Cribbins. And of course, he was the voice of the Wombles. Will be much missed.